# Should I use a tab bar or button at the bottom of my ViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uibutton, uitabbar

I'm just learning iOS, and I want to create an App which will have a few buttons at the bottom of the screen.

What I'm a bit unsure about is, I know you can use a tab bar down there, but is that what you should always use when you want a button at the bottom of the screen? or there's no need to use a tab bar, and you can just put a normal button down there?

Answer (score 1):

According to apple's documentation, `UITabBar` is a control used for displaying views.

> A tab bar is a control, usually appearing across the bottom of the screen in the context of a tab bar controller, for giving the user one-tap, modal access to a set of views in an app.

If your goal with this "button" is to display other views, then you should use `UITabBar` component.

But if you are just searching for a "usual button", then you should use `UIButton` component.

Answer (score 1):

A tab bar is expected to allow the user to switch between, you know, tabs; the same bar appears at the bottom of each page, and it allows you to switch between them.  If that describes what you are trying to accomplish, then it would be appropriate.  If your button is meant for some different purpose, then a tab bar might be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

A tab bar (class `UITabBar`) is usually part of a tab bar controller (class `UITabBarController`). A button (`UIButton` is simply a way to respond to a tap or other actions within the button.

You want to use a tab bar and tab bar controller when you need to switch between different views and view controllers in your application. For example the Music app on your iPhone has a tab bar controller that switches between Artist, Playlist, Album, etc. These are different screens, or screens that look the same but show your music organized in a different way.

If all you want is to respond to a button, for example to print out to the console or show a message to the user that says "Hey, you've tapped the button", then a `UIButton` is what you need.

Also, a `UIButton` can have many actions, **Touch Up Inside** is probably the one you are looking for. This one will ensure the button has an action called if the user began a tap on the button, and let go of their finger while still on top of the button.

To summarize things:

- Use a `UIButton` if you simply want to respond to an action, and the most common action you will connect to the button is Touch Up Inside.
- Use a `UITabBarController` to have a way to switch between different views and view controllers.